# Error with sessions in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

The following snippet is returning an error, however the error goes away when there is no SESSION.

Here is the line that is referred to by the error:

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
```

Here is the class definition that the previous line is contained within:

```php
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller
{

    public function _construct()
    {        
        parent::_construct();
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        if(!user_id){
            $this->logout();
        }
    }


    public function index()
    {        
          $this->load->view('dashboard/inc/header_view');
          $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard_view');
          $this->load->view('dashboard/inc/footer_view');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->sess_destroy();
        redirect('/');
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please mention the error message. Without the error message it's quite impossible to get what you have done wrong.

Comment: Missing session library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your log out function

Where `$this->sess_destroy();` is

Replace with `$this->session->sess_destroy();` because you are missing the `session`

Make sure `$this->load->library('session');` is loaded.

```
public function _construct() {        
    parent::_construct();

    $this->load->library('session'); // Or Autoload it.

    if ($this->session->userdata('user_id') == FALSE) {
        $this->logout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have loaded the session-library.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the Session library first of all. To load session use below one of method.

```
 public function _construct()
    {        
        parent::_construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        if(!user_id){
            $this->logout();
        }
    }
```

or in `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you Abdula, wofgang, wyz it is ok now, there is no error in dashboard.php (controllers) but in user.php(controllers) ERROR:

Here is error in user.php:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: User::$user_model

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 19

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\apcodeigniter\application\controllers\user.php
Line: 19
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp\www\apcodeigniter\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Error line:

```
$data = $this->user_model->get(1);
```

and line:

```
$result = $this->user_model->delete($user_id);
```

and error line 19:

```
 $result = $this->user_model->get([
       'login' => $login,
       'password' => hash('sha256', $password . SALT)
   ]);
```